# Who Killed Barry Allen's mom

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, the-flash-2023

The movie *The Flash* rotates around his mom's death with consequences by past changes. So who is the actual killer? Is Barry's dad the killer or someone else?

Answer (score 3):

## The Reverse Flash

> Director Andy Muschietti recently sat down on The Discourse Podcast to give a firm answer. The Flash takes the canonical route, stating the Reverse Flash does, in fact, kill Barry's mom. This would have been explored further in the sequel, though any hope of a follow-up seems far gone at this point.

Source https://movieweb.com/the-flash-who-killed-barrys-mom/